# The inverse of bounded operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, inverse

Is the inverse of a bounded operator always bounded , if yes how to prove it ?

Comment: In which kind of spaces are you working? If you are working in Banach spaces, I think this can be a useful [topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133935/bounded-inverse-operator?rq=1)

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1580369

Answer (score 4):

If You consider an invertible, i.e. bijective and bounded linear operator $A:X\rightarrow Y$, between two Banach-spaces (it´s important they are complete), then as a consequence of Baires category theorem A is open (open mapping theorem) and so $A^{-1}:Y \rightarrow X$ is continuous, i.e. bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Let T be a bounded linear operator from a normed space X on to a normed space Y. If there exists a positive b such that 
$||Tx||\geq b ||x|| \ \forall x\in X,$
then $T^{-1}$ exists and is bounded.

Comment: I See that if $T^{-1}$ exists it would be bounded, but could you give an argument for the existence of $T^{-1}$?

Comment: In fact consider the right shift $T:\mathcal{l}^2\to \mathcal{l}^2,(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots)\mapsto (0,x_1,x_2,\dots)$. Then $\Vert Tx\Vert = \Vert x \Vert$, but $T$ is not surjective.

Comment: @user592521 https://www.math.cuhk.edu.hk/course_builder/1516/math4010/solution4.pdf
there you go!

Answer (score -2):

It depends on how you define "inverse" of an operator. In general, if you don't require it be bounded, then no. For example, consider the bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ onto $(-1,1)$. But sometimes we say an operator is invertable only if we can find a bounded operator such that the composition is identity.

Comment: thanks , here i suposed it invertible (so bijective ) and bounded !

Comment: , thanks , i think i found it here http://planetmath.org/boundedinversetheorem

Comment: @lucaluca It is exactly the question I linked you above

Comment: But *operator* means *linear operator* and there is no bounded linear operator from $\mathbb{R}$ to $(-1,1)$. So I don't understand this answer.