# inverse of sequence of 0, 1 matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a sequence of matrices $M_n$ with a certain pattern. All the entries of these matrices are 0's and 1's with each row containing  a maximum of three 1's. I know they are invertible. Is there any way to prove that the row sums of $\{M_n^{-1}\}$ are bounded uniformly for all $n?$

Comment: What are the dimensions of $M_n$? $k \times k$ for a fixed $k$?

Comment: It is 5n+3 for each n

Comment: $5n+3\times 5n+3.$

Answer (score 1):

Sure, they are bounded uniformly, although many of your specifications are not necessary for this result. There are finitely many possible $k \times k$ $(0,1)$-matrices; in particular there are finitely many invertible ones, and for each of those invertible matrices, the inverse has a finite operator norm (by the [bounded inverse theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_inverse_theorem), see also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1598155/the-inverse-of-bounded-operator?noredirect=1&lq=1)). Thus there is a maximum operator norm, $C$, and we have
$$
\|M_n^{-1}\| \le C \quad \forall n
$$
which implies that, for $u$ the vector of all $1$s,
$$
\|M_n^{-1} u\| \le C\|u\|.
$$
Now the vector $v_n = M_n^{-1} u$ is the vector of row-sums, and its entries are bounded above by $\|v_n\|$, which is in turn bounded above by $C\|u\|$. So the row-sums are uniformly bounded.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that the size of $M_n$ is not fixed k: $M_n$ are of size $5n+3\times 5n+3.$

Comment: @XYZ I figured, that the problem was too easy this way :) Okay.